# Starting class functions as threads loosing reference

Tags: c++, beginthread

i am working on a windows program, which does the hard work in threads
and the GUI stays in the main loop (in this case i use ImGui OpenGL3)

but with implementing more functions, the parameters are getting out of scope
when starting a work_thread
and the  function started by beginthread receives pointer showing to NULL
(in fact not changing the code but including another library provokes that this happens)

what is going on and how to prevent this from happening

here a raw represantation of my code

```
#include <process.h>


class JOBS
{
public:
  void jobA(char *path);

};

void JOBS::jobA(char*path) {   . .     }


class APP_DATA
{
public:
  JOBS jobs;

public:
  char *path;
};



void job_a_threadstarter(void* pParams )
{
APP_DATA *app=*(APP_DATA **)  pParams;   

  app->jobs.jobA(app->path);  
}


void job_starter(APP_DATA *app)
{     
  _beginthread(job_a_threadstarter,0,&app);        
}



int main(int, char**)
{
APP_DATA app; 
char workpath[99]="path_to_somewhere";

    .
    .

  app.path=workpath;
  job_starter(&app);



    .
    .
}
```

usually the code runs with no problems,
but some change in other routines and job_a_threadstarter is crashing as the pParams is referencing to NULL

i am using GNU G++ with mingw on a x64 Windows
compiling with c++11 switch and linking with -mwindows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing pointer to local variable (`app`) which is destroyed when `job_starter` ends

```
_beginthread(job_a_threadstarter,0,&app); // you are getting pointer to local variable
```

replace it by

```
_beginthread(job_a_threadstarter,0,app); // forward pointer to app
```

Comment: big thanks, that worked, just for future reference, job_a_threadstarter will now look like this (removing two stars)
void job_a_threadstarter(void* pParams )
{
APP_DATA *app=(APP_DATA *)  pParams;   

  app->jobs.jobA(app->path);  
}